# Why I am getting "OVER_QUERY_LIMIT" when using "placement" package in R

Tags: r, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

```
## install the package "placement" 
## install.packages("placement")
library(placement)
##============= First Run:
## Without using Google API Key
##  Get coordinates for the Empire State Building and Google
address <- c("350 5th Ave, New York, NY 10118, USA", 
             "1600 Amphitheatre Pkwy, Mountain View, CA 94043, USA")
 coordset <- geocode_url(address, auth ="standard_api",  privkey= "",
                         clean=TRUE, add_date='today', verbose=TRUE)
## View the returns
print(coordset[ , 1:5])
##============= Output:
## lat lng location_type formatted_address           status
## 1  NA  NA          <NA>              <NA> OVER_QUERY_LIMIT
## 2  NA  NA          <NA>              <NA> OVER_QUERY_LIMIT
```

I have used only one set of lat-long so I am not sure why the OVER_QUERY_LIMIT should kick in. Looking forward to a resolution on this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Google Maps no longer allows you to hit their API for free, see https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/usage-and-billing